# Is there a CSS or Javascript solution to change the background image of the current page’s navigation tab?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way using JavaScript to write a conditional piece of code that checks if you are on a certain url or id, and if you are, loads an "on" background image for a a certain tab?

Is their an easier way to do this without using JavaScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. I'll split this answer into two parts to try and address both of the (implied) questions; albeit I'd like to see some actual mark-up before I address the JavaScript possibility.

---

CSS `id`-based conditional background changes, I'm assuming that the `id` is on the `body` tag, but that assumption isn't explicit in the code, so as long as it's an ancestor of the element with the relevant `id` this same approach will work:

```
#homePageId #tabToGoToHomePage {
    background-image: url('path/to/homePageImage.png');
}

#siteMapPageId #tabToGoToSiteMapPage {
    background-image: url('path/to/siteMapPageImage.png');
}

#contactPageId #tabToGoToContactPage {
    background-image: url('path/to/contactPageImage.png');
}

/* ...and so on... */
```

If there are multiple elements that represent a link to a particular page, you can (obviously, I suppose) use a class-name for those elements and in the CSS selector.

---

URL-based conditional background changes are a little more dependant on your html structure, though. Posting your mark-up would be a help.

The following is based on the following mark-up, and without seeing yours I'm unable to provide anything more specific. It should be adaptable to your circumstances though:

HTML:

```
<ul><!-- primary navigation -->
    <li><a href="#" class="navigation goHome" data-link="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navigation goAbout" data-link="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navigation goClients" data-link="clients">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navigation goContact" data-link="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- other content -->
<ul><!-- secondary navigation -->
    <li><a href="#" class="navigation goHome" data-link="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navigation goAbout" data-link="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navigation goClients" data-link="clients">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="navigation goContact" data-link="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation');
var url = 'http://www.example.com/about/';
// in real life use something like:
// var url = document.location;

if (url.charAt(url.length-1) == '/') {
    url = url.substr(0,url.length - 1);
    // I'm assuming that the pages are all in their own directories,
    // this gets rid of any trailing '/' characters
}
var curPage = url.split('/').pop().toLowerCase();

for (i=0; i<tabs.length; i++){
    if (tabs[i].getAttribute('data-link').toLowerCase() == curPage){
        tabs[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        /* or:
        tabs[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://path/to/image.png")';
        */
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/v6PUx/).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [JQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)
It allows quite a bit of customization and events that could be useful. Like the load event which is "triggered after the content of a remote tab has been loaded." You could then swap out an image placed on the tab.